# JavaScript Show invisible divs on click

Tags: javascript, html, css, button, icons

I ran into a problem that when I click on the button, it just flips the icon but only makes the invisible fields visible on the second click. Are there any idea how to do it?
(Heres a gif to show my problem: https://ibb.co/cvz7pWC )
Also heres my code :

```js
function moreSoc() {
    
    var moresoc = document.getElementById("moresoc");
    var btnText = document.getElementById("mbtn");

    if (moresoc.style.display === "none" ) {
        moresoc.style.display = "block";
        mbtn.innerHTML = "More ▲";
    } else {
        moresoc.style.display = "none";
        mbtn.innerHTML = "More ▼"
    }

}
```

```css
.morebutton {
    border: none;
    background: #fff;
    color: #111;
    font-size: 32px;
}

#moresoc {
    display: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper more">
            <button class="morebutton" id="mbtn" onclick="moreSoc()">More ▲</button>
        </div>
        <section class="social-links" id="moresoc">
            <div class="wrapper">
                <h2>Others</h2>
                    <div class="social-link facebook">
                        <p>Facebook</p>
                    </div>
                    <div class="social-link instagram">
                        <p>Instagram</p>
                    </div>
                    <div class="social-link twitter">
                        <p>Twitter</p>
                    </div>
                    <div class="social-link youtube">
                        <p>Youtube</p>
                    </div>
            </div>
        </section>
```

Comment: It is because on the first click `moreSoc` doesn't have a `style.display` property set so it is set to none, then on the second click it is set to block. (`style.property` only checks styles set directly on the element, not associated by css rules)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This could be to do with you not being to read `element.style.display` as `none` the first time round. This is because it has not yet been set by JavaScript, but just by css. I suggest changing your `if` statement to check for **not** `"block"`.

```js
function moreSoc() {
    
    var moresoc = document.getElementById("moresoc");
    var btnText = document.getElementById("mbtn");

    if (moresoc.style.display != "block" ) {
        moresoc.style.display = "block";
        mbtn.innerHTML = "More ▲";
    } else {
        moresoc.style.display = "none";
        mbtn.innerHTML = "More ▼"
    }

}
```

```css
.morebutton {
    border: none;
    background: #fff;
    color: #111;
    font-size: 32px;
}

#moresoc {
    display: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper more">
            <button class="morebutton" id="mbtn" onclick="moreSoc()">More ▼</button>
        </div>
        <section class="social-links" id="moresoc">
            <div class="wrapper">
                <h2>Others</h2>
                    <div class="social-link facebook">
                        <p>Facebook</p>
                    </div>
                    <div class="social-link instagram">
                        <p>Instagram</p>
                    </div>
                    <div class="social-link twitter">
                        <p>Twitter</p>
                    </div>
                    <div class="social-link youtube">
                        <p>Youtube</p>
                    </div>
            </div>
        </section>
```

Answer (score 0):

[`ElementCSSInlineStyle.style`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ElementCSSInlineStyle/style) only returns (or sets) inline styles on an element. On your first click there is no inline display property to read so your condition sets it to `none`. On the second click your condition finds `none` and sets it to `block`.

The answer to look for `!block` solves this immediate problem but it stills ties your styling to your js rather than keeping it in your CSS. This means that if the default display property of your div needs to change in your layout (inline-block, flex, etc) you would need to change it in your js as well as your CSS.

For this reason I would recommend not using inline styles at all but rather rather use [`Element.classList`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/classList) to manage applied styles from your CSS – in this case just the adding/removing of a `.hidden` class that sets display to none without having to know what the appropriate visible display default is.

Also, since you are querying the button element in your code anyway, it would be better to apply the click listener from your js as well rather than inline.

```js
function moreSoc() {
  const moresoc = document.getElementById("moresoc");
  
  if (moresoc.classList.contains('hidden')) {
    moresoc.classList.remove('hidden');
    mbtn.innerHTML = "More ▲";
  } else {
    moresoc.classList.add('hidden');
    mbtn.innerHTML = "More ▼"
  }
}

const mbtn = document.getElementById("mbtn");
mbtn.addEventListener('click', moreSoc);
```

```css
.morebutton {
    border: none;
    background: #fff;
    color: #111;
    font-size: 32px;
}

#moresoc {
    
}

.hidden {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper more">
  <button class="morebutton" id="mbtn">More ▲</button>
</div>
<section class="social-links hidden" id="moresoc">
  <div class="wrapper">
    <h2>Others</h2>
    <div class="social-link facebook">
      <p>Facebook</p>
    </div>
    <div class="social-link instagram">
      <p>Instagram</p>
    </div>
    <div class="social-link twitter">
      <p>Twitter</p>
    </div>
    <div class="social-link youtube">
      <p>Youtube</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```